# markers with custom images are not showing up in IE6

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Yeah i have read through tons of posts about markers not showing up in IE6, 7, 8, etc - i tried later versions as well.

The trouble is it does show some times, and some times it does not.

I am using Internet Explorer ActiveX control to display a map with markers inside Win32 application, XP SP2.

I've tried MarkerManager, no luck. Tried changing security options as well.

Anyway here is the code...Any fresh ideas would be greatly appreciated. THANK YOU.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var AllOtherUnits = [];
  var MyUnit;
  var currentMarker;
  var OtherUnit;

  function initialize(Lat, Lng) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.set("streetViewControl", false);
  }

  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
   map.setCenter(latlng);
  }

  function GotoLatLngZoom(Lat, Lang, Zoom) {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
   map.setCenter(latlng);
   map.setZoom(Zoom);
  }

  function ClearMarkers() {
    if (AllOtherUnits) {
      for (i in AllOtherUnits) {
        AllOtherUnits[i].setMap(null);
      }
    }
  }

  function PutOtherUnitOn(Lat, Lang, FullName) {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      title: FullName,
      icon: "http://www.commoditytradingforum.com/Police-32x32.ico"
    });
    AllOtherUnits.push(marker);
  }

  function PutOtherUnitOff(FullName) {
    if (AllOtherUnits) {
      for (i in AllOtherUnits) {
        if (AllOtherUnits[i].title == FullName) {
          AllOtherUnits[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
    }
  }


  function PutMyUnitOn(Lat, Lang, FullName) {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
   MyUnit = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      title: FullName,
      icon: "http://www.commoditytradingforum.com/Police-car-32.ico"
    });
  }

  function PutMyUnitOff() {
    if (MyUnit != null) {
      MyUnit.setMap(null)
    }
  }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize(40.714776,-74.019213)">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  <div id="latlong">
  <input type="hidden" id="LatValue" >
  <input type="hidden" id="LngValue" >
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is not a supported browser for the Google Maps API v3:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport

```
 Which web browsers does the Google Maps JS API support?
 The Google Maps JavaScript API supports the following web browsers:

 Google Maps JavaScript API V3:

 IE 8.0+ (Windows) *
 Firefox 3.0+ (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
 Safari 4+ (Mac OS X, iOS)
 Chrome (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
 Android
 BlackBerry 6
 Dolfin 2.0+ (Samsung Bada)
 * Internet Explorer's Compatibility View is not supported.
```

Comment: Well, with IE8 i was not able to get it working at all! With IE6 it at least works most of the time...

Comment: The code you posted works for me in IE8.  Doesn't show any markers, but doesn't look like the code to display them is called.

Comment: Yeah, the code to show the markers is being called from application. And after i installed IE8 for tests, it didnt work at all, maybe its about security options...I tried changing them, but it did not help.

Comment: While it is nice that the code to display the markers is called from the application, I can't reproduce the problem with what you have posted.

Comment: I have just installed IE8 on another vmware machine and tested, and it worked indeed...

Comment: Can anybody tell me which security settings exactly do i need to enable to get this thing run smoothly? When i open the local file with IE6, it popups security alert, i do "Allow blocked content" and its being displayed ok. But it seems the settings are not being saved for current user session, because when i lunch the app then, the marker is not displayed, and no infobar is shown in my embedded TWebBrowser controls.

Comment: nevermind, i've figured it out. that was the issue in the calling code.